# In BGE is it possible to leave a boolean function "unapplied"

Tags: modifiers, game-engine

I am attempting to make an App using BGE where I can dynamically "slice" through complex object as if looking at it with a CT scanner.    To do this, I have created a "cube" that surrounds the object and I apply a boolean *intersection* modifier to the cube and complex object.   I have also created a mouse sensor and a very simple python script to move the cube when the mouse button is clicked.

When modeling the scene, the boolean modifier does not need to be "applied" and I can dynamically slice through the object.  However, when I (P)lay the Blender Game, the last boolean intersection remains, despite the fact that I can move the cube in the simulation.

Is there some way to *not* apply the modifier so that I can dynamically modify the position of the cube and the shape of the boolean intersection within the "Game?" and not just when modeling?

My alternate (unwieldy) solution, which I have not tested yet, is to constantly load a copy of the complex object, use the script to create the boolean intersect modifier and then to apply it.  This might be very sluggish, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure the boolean modifier is not supported in the BGE (2.79).

Comment: Are you aware a way to simulate a boolean effect in BGE?

Comment: This is really not easy as the BGE has very limited mesh editing capabilities. Boolean operations typically need quite a lot of them. I guess you need to dig deep into the bag of tricks. There are some, but it is a lot of work e.g. shape keys, material animations, UV-manipulation, Vertex relocation via BGE API  ... .